# Prime numbers/Composite number

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove or disprove, that for all positive integer numbers $a$ and $b$, if $b\vert (a^{(b^2+5b-6)}- 81)$ then $b$ is a composite number or $b$ is smaller than $6$.

Could anyone help with this? any hint/idea will be appreciated. I was thinking prove by contraposition, from $b$ is a prime number and $b \geq 6$ then get: $b$ does not divides $(a^{(b^2+5b-6)}- 81)$, which means $(a^{(b^2+5b-6)}- 81)$ is a prime number or a composite number which does not have $b$ as a factor, maybe?

Comment: Out of curiosity where does this question come from?

Comment: just one of my homework questions, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $b$ is a prime number $>6$. Then $b^2+5b-6=(b-1)(b+6)$. So Fermat's little theorem tells u if $gcd(a,b)=1$ then $a^{b^2+5b-6}\equiv1$ $mod$ $b$ and hence $b|80$. This is a contradiction as prime factors of $80$ are $<6$. Thus $b|a$ and hence $b|81$. Again a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $b$ is prime, then $$a^{b^2+5b-6}-81=a^{(b+6)(b-1)}-81\equiv (a^{b+6})^{b-1}-81\equiv1-81\equiv80\pmod b$$ by Fermat's little theorem. Thus $b|80$. The only prime factors of $80$ are $2,3$ and $5$, which are all less than $6$.